# Why Apple have heightForRowForIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I mean that looks like an overkill. It already has cellForRowForIndexPath

Once UITableViewSourceDelegate got the cell, it can easily got the height by computing the height of that cell.

So why?

Comment: I has a good answer that's not obvious. Why is this a bad question?

Comment: Not constructive? Who knows about the intricacies. not to mention that I got an awesome answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called for every row in the table in order to compute its total height and consequently set the correct size of the scroll indicator.

On the other hand `cellForRowForIndexPath` is called only for the visible cells.

Comment: That seems like a good answer. Are you sure? I mean if we do not use the scroll indicator, will this be an issue?

Comment: As a general statement the `UITableView` needs to know the height of its content in order to be drawn properly. Suppose you have a table with 1000 rows, how would you compute such height? You could either call 1000 times `heightForRowAtIndexPath` or allocate 1000 cells in memory and query them about their heights. Clearly the second solution is terrible in term of performances, so that's why `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is there.